# JSONException error when Eclipse creates a new spring-boot project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

After eclipse installed spring-tools plug-in, the new spring starter project the first step JSONException error, can not continue. May I ask what is the reason? Can solve it?

eclipse:Mars Release (4.5.0)

spring-tools:3.8.4

[image: error show]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can use http://start.spring.io to create skeleton project and then import into eclipse

Comment: Does it happen with the current releases, which is at least Eclipse 4.7.2?

Comment: @nitind I have reinstalled the latest version, the result is still the same

Comment: This might be a "spring-tools" bug, then. Are you following some guide that's telling you to put in this value?

Comment: @nitind I use start.spring.io generate a project, import eclipse successfully run, again create a new spring started project, and finally no longer appear this error.Anyway, thanks a lot.